# What's the difference between Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In and Extensible Choice Parameter plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In in Jenkins, and I see another plugin somewhat with similar name called Extensible Choice Parameter plugin.

Can anyone throw some light on the differences between these two plugins?

Thanks,
Ra's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both plugins allows advanced configuration of parameter choices for a job.

Below is a brief list of their respected features, based on the plugins' description pages.

[**Extended Choice Parameter**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter)

- Is older (first release in 2010, last release in 2016)
- Has more installs (20K vs 15K).
- Allowed parameter types: single select, multiselect, radio buttons,
  check boxes.
- Both parameter values list and default parameter values can be
  specified via: UI, file (filesystem path or URL), Groovy script.
- Allows to specify complex parameter values via JSON.
- Allows to customise choice UI by specifying parameter field type (e.g.
  create color-picker).

[**Extensible Choice Parameter**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter)

- Is newer (first release in 2013, last release in 2018)
- Has less installs (15K vs 20K).
- Allows to specify choices list globally in Configure System page and share them between multiple jobs.
- Supports Groovy script to generate choices.
- Supports filesystem choice: list files in a directory by a mask.
- Allows to choose value not in choice list and optionally add it to the choice list.
- Allows to provide choices with Extension Points.

Comment: Can both be used from a declarative pipeline? So far I have only seen it for Extended Choice Parameter Plugin - https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin/pull/25

Comment: Seems only the older one (Extended Choice) supports pipelines - https://github.com/jenkinsci/extensible-choice-parameter-plugin/pull/47